# JSON encode returns the same type

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

How do i encode this in json format? I am receiving the same data in my 1st, 2nd and 3rd if i put 1st, while if i put "2nd"=>$row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaNXI.jpg), "3rd"=>$row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaNXI.jpg) the same data as the 1st is being retrieved. Please someone help, Thanks.

Here is my php

```
    $sql = "select n_name, shortcut, IF(rank = 1>2, 2, shortcut) AS 1st, IF(rank = 1<2, shortcut, shortcut) AS 2nd, 
 IF(rank = 3=3, 1, shortcut) as 3rd from team inner join nonsport on team.n_id = nonsport.n_id group by n_name";                         

 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("n_name"=>$row[0], "1st"=>$row[1], "2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[3]));
 }

echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));



mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Here is the example. What im trying to do is in the first column to put the BBBB into 2nd and CCCC into 3rd.

[image: Example Image]

Here is the result i am getting.

```
{"nresults":[{"n_name":"Song Composition ","1st":"AAAA","2nd":"AAAA","3rd":"AAAA"},

{"nresults":[{"n_name":"Song Composition ","1st":"BBBB","2nd":"BBBB","3rd":"BBBB"},

{"nresults":[{"n_name":"Song Composition ","1st":"CCCC","2nd":"CCCC","3rd":"CCCC"},
```

And here is what i am trying to do.

```
{"nresults":[{"n_name":"Song Composition ","1st":"AAAA","2nd":"BBBB","3rd":"CCCC"},
```

Can someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Yes sir, they are stored that way

Comment: The response only sir, I want to retrieve in 1 line the 1st with the 1st value, the second with the second value.

Comment: But this one is giving me as 1st, 2nd and 3rd with the first value, then another line with 1st,2nd and 3rd as the 3rd value.

Comment: no sir, only up to 3rd

Answer (score 0):

This is not a nice solution but it should help you.

```
$c = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($c == 0) {
       array_push($response, "n_name"=>$row[0], "1st"=>$row[2]);
    }
    else if ($c == 1) {
       array_push($response, "2nd"=>$row[3]);
    }
    else if ($c == 2) {
       array_push($response, "3rd"=>$row[4]);
    }
    else {
       break;
    }
    $c++;
}
```

An better approach would be to adapt the SQL query. But to help you with this I need more information about the tables `team` and `nonsport`. Also I would suggest to avoid ordinal number suffixes (st, nd, rd) if it's possible.